# MVVM and Entity Framework interaction data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvm

My application retrieves data using Entity Framework. I'm not sure if I'm interacting with the entity correctly using the MVVM pattern.

1. I have data problems: for example, to access them I need to call tasks every time both in the constructor and in the `DeleteTask` function. How can I avoid this?
2. I also want to put data in a `TaskView` for the search facility in my application.

But it seems to me that I am mishandling the program logic somewhere.

I would be glad to any of your advice.

```
        public string TabName { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<TaskModel> _tasks;
        private TaskModel _selectTask;

        public ObservableCollection<TaskModel> Tasks
        {
            get { return _tasks; }
            set
            {
                _tasks = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Tasks");
            }
        }

        public TaskModel SelectTask
        {
            get { return _selectTask; }
            set
            {
                _selectTask = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectTask");
            }
        }

        public ICollectionView TasksView { get; set; }

        public ICommand DeleteTask
        {
            get
            {
                return new DelegateCommand(() =>
                {
                    using (TaskContext db = new TaskContext())
                    {
                        db.Task.Attach(SelectTask);
                        db.Task.Remove(SelectTask);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                        Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>(db.Task);
                        TasksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tasks);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public HomeViewModel()
        {
            using (TaskContext db = new TaskContext())
            {
                Tasks = new ObservableCollection<TaskModel>(db.Task);
                TasksView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Tasks);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error? Can you show the exception? might be the case where your DB is being disposed after the constructor is called.